# problems to save byte string in BLOB field (python, mysqldb)

Tags: python, sql, mysql-python

I could throw my pc out of my window...

i want to save a byte string to a BLOB field in my SQL Database.

For example:

```
a = 'example' # normal string
b = b'byteexample' # type bytestring
```

lets assume i have a Table in my database called "justatable" with a BLOB column called "ablob" i would do:

```
sql_a = "INSERT INTO justatest(ablob) VALUES ('%s')" % (a)

sql_b = "INSERT INTO justatest(ablob) VALUES ('%s')" % (b)
```

when executing:

```
cursor.execute(sql_a) # works
cursor.execute(sql_b) # doesn't work
```

why does MySQLdb throws an error???: ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'byteexample'')' at line 1")

why does it work with a normal string but not with a bytestring??

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens when you format a bytestring into a string:

```
>>> b = b'byteexample'
>>> sql_b = "INSERT INTO justatest(ablob) VALUES ('%s')" % (b)
>>> print(sql_b)
INSERT INTO justatest(ablob) VALUES ('b'byteexample'')
```

Now you see why it doesn't work?

By the way, you *really* **really** shouldn't use string formatting to construct SQL statements. It's prone to SQL injection. Use a proper mysql library that prepares the statements safely.